# Terminator automatically resizing

Tags: window, resize, terminator

I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu thing or a Terminator thing, but every time I launch terminator, it seems to resize to a different size every time.  Sometimes it shrinks a little, and some time a lot.  I have set the size that I want it to be in the config:

```
~$ cat .config/terminator/config 
[global_config]
  enabled_plugins = ,
[keybindings]
  full_screen = F10
[profiles]
 [[default]]
  scrollback_lines = 5000
  font = Monaco Bold 8
  use_system_font = False
  scrollback_infinite = True
  background_image = None
 [layouts]
[[default]]
[[[child1]]]
  type = Terminal
  parent = window0
  profile = default
[[[window0]]]
  type = Window
  parent = ""
  size = 1099, 800
[plugins]
```

Is there a way to stop it from trying to do anything automatically, and just open the same size every time?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in Ubuntu by saving my layout with a name besides `default`, say `basic_layout`. Then edit terminator's Launcher button to specifically use this layout on startup.

Open the terminator launcher file in your favorite editor:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop
```

Find this line:

```
Exec=terminator
```

And replace it with this line:

```
Exec=terminator -l basic_layout
```

Comment: Overwriting the "default" layout by clicking the "Save" button also worked for me. No need to adjust the launcher in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 16 and was having a hell of a time getting Terminator to launch with my layouts. I had to use a combination of the information running terminator layouts **

> terminator --layout=newsys

** from this guide to terminator [Guide to Terminator](http://www.linuxnov.com/the-complete-guide-to-configure-terminator-terminal-emulator-layouts/) with the information above

> Open the terminator launcher file in your favorite editor:
>
> sudo vim /usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop
>
> Find this line:
>
> Exec=terminator

So for me the line looks like

Exec=terminator --layout=RW_Layout

worked like a charm!

Comment: This looks like a rewording of the answer above from a year prior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wmctrl to reposition the Terminator window as well.
I created an alias to reposition it if I want:

```
alias stdwin='wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 1,0,40,810,600'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved in latest version of terminator - with v1.91 I don't see this issue.